# create an unique week variable NOT depending on the calendar in R

Tags: r, date, for-loop, time-series, week-number

I have a **daily** revenue time series `df` from `01-01-2014` to `15-06-2017` and I want to aggregate the daily revenue data to weekly revenue data and do the weekly predictions. Before I aggregate the revenue, I need to `create a continuously week variable`, which will **NOT** start from week 1 again when a new year starts. Since 01-01-2014 was not Monday, so I decided to start my first week from **06-01-2014**.

My `df` now looks like this

```
         date    year month     total 
 7    2014-01-06 2014     1 1857679.4   
 8    2014-01-07 2014     1 1735488.0    
 9    2014-01-08 2014     1 1477269.9    
 10   2014-01-09 2014     1 1329882.9    
 11   2014-01-10 2014     1 1195215.7  
 ...  
 709  2017-06-14 2017     6 1677476.9
 710  2017-06-15 2017     6 1533083.4
```

I want to create a unique `week variable` starting from `2014-01-06` until the last row of my dataset (1257 rows in total), which is `2017-06-15`.

I wrote a loop:

```
   week = c()
   for (i in 1:179) {
   week = rep(i,7)
   print(week)
   }
```

However, the result of this loop is not saved for each iteration.  When I type `week`, it just shows `179,179,179,179,179,179,179`

Where is the problem and how can I add 180, 180, 180, 180 after the repeat loop?

And if **I will add more new data after 2017-06-15**, how can I create the weekly variable automatically depending on my end of row (date)? (In other words, by doing that, I don't need to calculate how many daily observations I have and divide it by 7 and plus the rest of the dates to become the week index)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
 week = c()
 for (i in 1:184) {
    for (j in 1:7) {
            week[j+(i-1)*7] = i
    }
 }
 week = as.data.frame(week)
```

I created a `week variable`, and from week 1 to the week 184 (end of my dataset). For each week number, I repeat 7 times because there are 7 days in a week. Later I assigned the week variable to my `data frame`.

Answer (score 4):

Does this work

```
library(lubridate)

#DATA
x = data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = ymd("2014-01-06"),
        to = ymd("2017-06-15"), length.out = 15))

#Add year and week for each date
x$week = year(x$date) + week(x$date)/100

#Convert the addition of year and week to factor and then to numeric
x$week_variable = as.numeric(as.factor(x$week))

#Another alternative
x$week_variable2 = floor(as.numeric(x$date - min(x$date))/7) + 1

x
#         date    week week_variable week_variable2
#1  2014-01-06 2014.01             1              1
#2  2014-04-05 2014.14             2             13
#3  2014-07-04 2014.27             3             26
#4  2014-10-02 2014.40             4             39
#5  2014-12-30 2014.52             5             52
#6  2015-03-30 2015.13             6             65
#7  2015-06-28 2015.26             7             77
#8  2015-09-26 2015.39             8             90
#9  2015-12-24 2015.52             9            103
#10 2016-03-23 2016.12            10            116
#11 2016-06-21 2016.25            11            129
#12 2016-09-18 2016.38            12            141
#13 2016-12-17 2016.51            13            154
#14 2017-03-17 2017.11            14            167
#15 2017-06-15 2017.24            15            180
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I think this is not exactly what I want. I need to create a week variable, starting from 1 and repeat 7 times until the end of my dataset (now is 2017-06-15).

Comment: And I would like to start my first week from Monday. So my data will start from `2014-01-06`. The method you provided was great, but it starts from Wednesday (2014-01-01). How could I change it?